# Cypress: how to simulate explicit click

Tags: cypress

Cypress loses focus, and fails the test

Always fails in command line interface, flaky in UI mode

1. [Unsuccessful run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc586.png)
2. [Successful run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPu2j.png)

```
it("Copy and paste tasks", () => {
        // Get the row count
        cy.get("rowClass").then(rows => {
            // Copy the last row
            cy.get("rowClass").eq(-1).find("class to select whole row").click();
            cy.get("body").type("{ctrl+c}");
            cy.get("rowClass").eq(-1).should("have.class", "cut-copy-animation");

            // Select the first row and paste
             cy.get("rowClass").eq(0).find("class to select whole row").click();
            cy.get("body").type("{ctrl+v}"); // fails here

            // Row count should increase
            cy.get("rowClass").should("have.length", rows.length + 1);
        });
```

cy.get(id).focus() or cy.get(id).click() doesn't work.

**Only explicit click via mouse on an element works (while cypress is running tests in UI mode)**

How to simulate explicit click in cypress?

Comment: I use https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events

Comment: Try adding assertions (ie. should('be.visible')) before you interact with an element. Sometimes the speeds on your local are much faster than the app loading.